# VBA-Replacing #N/A with 0 in a named range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to replace #N/A values in my named range, from a previous operation by using this code:

```
For Each cl In m
    If cl.Value = "#N/A" Then
        Set cl.Value = 0
    End If
Next cl
```

But this is giving me junk output.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you check for an error is to use the `IsError()` function. The variant value won't contain the string "#N/A" although the cell's `.Text` value would (but only if the cell width if big enough). So `IsError` is a safer bet. Once you've established that your cell contains an error your next task is to find which one, using the `CVErr()` function. For completeness I've included all the errors in the sample code below (and an explanation of the functions can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211091(v=office.12).aspx.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim v As Variant

Set cell = Sheet1.Range("A1")
v = cell.Value

If IsError(v) Then
    Select Case v
        Case CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
        Case CVErr(xlErrNA)
            cell.Value = 0
        Case CVErr(xlErrName)
        Case CVErr(xlErrNull)
        Case CVErr(xlErrNum)
        Case CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Case CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Case Else
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: very neat solution with the `Select` :)

Comment: @ShaiRado, would love to claim it as my own, but it's the recommended pattern on the Microsoft site!

Answer (score 5):

Simpler version:

```
'Set range to whatever you like
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A2")

'Loop all the cells in range
For Each cell In rng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(cell) Then
        'If cell contains #N/A, then set the value to 0
        cell.value = 0
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yup, it does come out clear this way. Have an upvote. I still prefer to keep this kind of thing on the worksheet though.

Comment: It is correct that this could be done (quite easily) without using VBA, by simply using `=IF(ISNA(A1); 0; A1)`. I just assumed there was a reason for using VBA.

Comment: Fair point. But as I'm an old cat, I always question the use of VBA. It was cool in 1997, but can cause more trouble than it's worth sometimes. (e.g. it's difficult to version control, many organisations disallow opening xls or xlsm files).

Answer (score 2):

A few options.

1. Keep everything on the worksheet (my favourite since then you haven't buried critical functionality in the VBA layer). Use the formula `=IFNA(A1, 0)` where A1 contains the cell to test, or `=IF(ISNA(A1), 0, A1)` in older versions of Excel.
2. Use VBA. If `v` is the `Variant` containing the cell value then use

   ```
   If IsError(v) Then
       If v = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
           'Set the cell to 0
       End If
   End If
   ```

   Where you need the nested block since VBA does not support short-circuited `And`, and the test for equality `=` can cause an error with some variant types.
3. Use the arguably clearest

   `If Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(v)`

As a final cautionary remark against using a VBA solution for this, note that (2) and (3) have the tendency to obliterate formulas whose parameters depend on cells with values set to `#N/A` as `#N/A` tends to *propagate* through most built-in Excel functions.

Comment: I really like this answer - the function option is definitely worth considering.

Answer (score -1):

You may try your code like this...

```
For Each cl In m
    If IsError(cl) Then
        cl.Value = 0
    End If
Next cl
```

Comment: That will replace other errors too such as #VALUE! And #NUM.

Comment: That's true. But ideally there shouldn't be any such error on the sheet if data and formulas are managed correctly. In this case, the proposed code will work if there is only one error #N/A only in the range. :)